# how to add if condition during the loop in angular repeater

Tags: angularjs, if-statement, conditional-statements, repeat

```
<ul ng-repeat="lay in lays">
    <li ng-repeat="color in colors">

    </li>
</ul>
```

this loops do very well, I want to add if condition during the loops:

```
if(lay == 0 && $index == 0){ {{color}} } else{ "white" }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a function like this

```
<ul ng-repeat="lay in lays">
    <li ng-repeat="color in colors">{{render(lay, $index, color)}}</li>
</ul>

$scope.render = function (lay, index, color) {
    if (lay == 0 && index == 0) return color;
    else return "white";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion you should filter your data in the controllers, its much more comprehensive and better maintained.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul ng-repeat="lay in lays">
    <li ng-repeat="color in colors">
        {{ (lay == 0) && (($index == 0) && color || "white") || "white" }}
    </li>
</ul>
```

No need to use controller.

Comment: @sza I've done similar project. If rupert can provide a jsfiddle, I can prove it to you.

Comment: I can't put the code `{{ (lay == 0) && (($index == 0) && color || "white") || "white" }}` into the tag "li" as an Attr